# Sending email to dynamic sender address using MEAN and Node Mailer

Tags: node.js, angular, nodemailer

I am struck with sending email to dynamic sender address using MEAN(Angular 2+) and Node Mailer. I couldn't find a single example or tutorial for sending email to dynamic sender address. Can any one give a very simple example with single value with html, TS, service and server file codes please.

Answer (score -1):

```
var nodeMailer = require('nodemailer');
function sendEmail(email, callback) {
    var transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
            pass: 'password'
        }
    });
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Email Verification',
        text: 'Hi there, a simple test mail'
        //html: '' //for html code
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, 'success');
        }
    });
}
```

Everything is same till HTTP call. Just call the function with required email